# Average rejection response time after a PhD interview

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, interview, rejection

More than one week ago I had a PhD interview with a British university which probably has so many applicants on a rolling basis but I have not yet received the final result of my application. I wonder if there are professors here experienced in interviewing applicants who can tell me usually at most how long should I wait for receiving a rejection? I mean, does a rejection response usually happen just a couple of days after the interview?

Comment: It depends so much on the school, professor, existence/non-existence of a waitlist, and on pure chance, that the only possible answer is "it depends". Good luck.

Comment: You are likely to get a rejection sooner than you get an acceptance. If you are clearly not suitable they want to let you know. If you might be ok they will wait until they have a good pool from which to select. As Yogi Berra said, "It ain't over til its over". Nor does the "average" help you in any case. The deviation is large.